# Несколько окон. Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, окно

Вообщем, не понимаю как правильно создавать второе окно. Есть функция addTimer(), как метод класса главного окна MainWindow.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    MainWindow();
protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *e);
    QMap<QTimer*,QTextEdit*> getTimers();
private:
    QToolBar *toolbar;
    void setToolBar();
    QLabel *timelbl;

    QLabel *mainTimerLbl;
    QTextEdit *mainTimerDescriptionLbl;

    QListWidget *listW;
    QMap<QTimer*,QTextEdit*> timers_descriptions;

    QWindow *addWindow;
    void addTimer();
};
```

Сама функция

```
void MainWindow::addTimer()
{
    addWindow = new QWindow();
    addWindow->resize(200,120);
    addWindow->setTitle("New Timer");

    QLabel *timeLbl = new QLabel("Time",this);
    timeLbl->setGeometry(20,60,50,20);

    QTimeEdit *timeEdit = new QTimeEdit(this);
    timeEdit->setGeometry(90,65,100,25);
    addWindow->show();
}
```

Вообщем, окно создаётся, но QLabel и QTimeEdit не появляется. Подскажите как правильно

Comment: похоже что вы указываете не того родителя для виджетов. полагаю что вам нужно заменить `this` на `addWindow` но это только предположение: неплохо бы было описать решаемую задачу.

Comment: Пишет что нету конструктора подходящего. Вообщем я создаю свой таймер, и это функция добавления нового таймера. Хочу чтобы для ввода времени и описания таймера создавалось новое окно.

Comment: Передавая `this` в конструктор, вы только передаете задачу управления памятью над этим объектом родителю. т.е `MainWindow`.  Что бы `QLabel` и `QTimeEdit` отображались добавьте `QLayout` и уже в него добавить кнопку и лейбл с помощью метода `addWidget`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html) служит для других задач, для десктопных приложений лучше использовать `QWidget, QDialog, или QMainWindow`.

Возьмем QWidget, тогда отображение вашего окна и его содержимого будет таким:

```cpp
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    //...
private:
    QWidget* addWindow;
};

void MainWindow::addTimer()
{
    addWindow = new QWidget();
    addWindow->resize(200,120);
    addWindow->setWindowTitle("New Timer");

    QLabel *timeLbl = new QLabel("Time");
    timeLbl->setGeometry(20,60,50,20);

    QTimeEdit *timeEdit = new QTimeEdit();
    timeEdit->setGeometry(90,65,100,25);

    // Добавим на окно менеджер вертикального расположения элементов
    addWindow->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
    // А теперь, при помощи менеджера расположения, добавим сами виджеты на окно
    addWindow->layout()->addWidget(timeLbl);
    addWindow->layout()->addWidget(timeEdit);

    addWindow->show();
}
```

Про QVBoxLayout можно почитать [здесь](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvboxlayout.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло)